# How to validate a secret present in headers of a post request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, reactive

I have to implement a POST rest API. For authentication, the client will send us a secret (static) in headers and we have to validate it on the server. One way is to access the secret in the Controller and validate it. But does Spring provide any built-in support for it? Or a better way to do the same, where business and security logic is kept at a diff

Following is the brute force way:

```
    @PostMapping("/v1/something")
    fun initiateSomething(
        @RequestBody @Valid request: RequstToDoSomething,
        @RequestHeader headers: Map<String, String>
    ): Mono<ResponseToDOSOmething> {
        if (headers["secret"] != "CONFIDENTIAL_SECRET")
            throw Exception()
        return service.process(request)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spring provides many possibilities to do it, starting from AOP to request filters, but I recommend you to have a look at [OncePerRequestFilter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-onceperrequestfilter) or [Filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter).

Answer (score 0):

In my practice, I will use Spring's Filter feature to achieve this functionality.

like this:

```
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@Order(value = 1)
@Component
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String contextPath = request.getRequestURI();
    // check the path which you want to intercept
    if (contextPath.startsWith("/your/path")) {
        // get your parameter
        String security = request.getHeader("secret");
        // check your parameter
        if (security==null || !validateSecurity(security)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write("Have not been authenticated");
            return;
        }
    }
    // if validate pass will go to the controller
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

private Boolean validateSecurity(String security) {
    return "security".equals(security);
}
```

}